# Visual Studio Find and Replace with regex and single/double quotes

Tags: regex, visual-studio

How to use VS Find/Replace to replace:

**this**: $('a[name="lnkFind"]').on('click', function

**with this**: $(document).on("click", "a[name='lnkFind']", function

I'm not sure which characters need to be escaped - single or double quotes or both? None of the patters I've tried seem to find a match.

Comment: Please provide a comment when downvoting to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape many of these characters.

Find/Replace will complain about the un-escaped `(` and `)`, even the bare `(` at the end because it's missing a matching `)`. Also the square brackets, which are used for character sets, and finally the `$`.

So this should work as the pattern:

```
\$\('a\[name="lnkFind"\]'\).on\('click', function
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a list of special characters in Regular Expressions.

`$`, `.`, `[`, `]` should all be escaped.

http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html

Comment: Thanks but I've spent some time on this already. I'm looking for a working example with my original text values.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and read Mastering Regular Expressions (http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124).

Comment: `(` and `)` should be escaped as well

Answer (score 1):

Except in special cases (such as vim regex), in general you can escape any and all special characters in regex to get their literal form, *i.e.* escaping a special character that doesn't need to be escaped, won't do any harm.

That said, here's the minimum that needs to be escaped:

```
\$\('a\[name="lnkFind"]')\.on\('click', function
```

I don't think you'll need to escape anything in the replacement, because only a `$` or `\` followed by a number will be interpreted.